# Day/Night time range for camera

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

This script actually turns ON/OFF night mode of Camera via GPIO output.
Need to setup range somehow.

Let's say the raspberry restart & script start let's say at 21:00 what's already night but now the script doesn't know that.

How can I do a range 
between sunrise and sunset = DAY

between sunset and sunrise = NIGHT

Thanks, my code:

```
#import datetime
from suntime import Sun, SunTimeException

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # Import Raspberry Pi GPIO library
from time import sleep # Import the sleep function from the time module


from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")



GPIO.setwarnings(False) # Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW) # Set pin 8 to be an output pin and set initial value to low (off)


print("Current Time =", current_time)


latitude = 51.34
longitude = -0.95

sun = Sun(latitude, longitude)

# Get today's sunrise and sunset in UTC
today_sr = sun.get_sunrise_time()
today_ss = sun.get_sunset_time()
print('Today at Heckfieldplace the sun raised at {} and get down at {} UTC'.
      format(today_sr.strftime('%H:%M'), today_ss.strftime('%H:%M')))


sunraise = today_sr.strftime('%H:%M')
sunset = today_ss.strftime('%H:%M')



while True:
        if current_time >= sunraise and current_time <= sunset:
                GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
                print("DAY")

        elif current_time >= sunset and current_time <= sunraise:
                GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
                print("NIGHT")

        else:
                print("Nothing")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sunrise and sunset are relative to midnight of the current day, so sunset is always a greater number than sunrise.  So your second conditional for night is an impossible condition.  If you created a "tomorrow's sunrise" variable, or just midnight, you could use that.  Edit: for that matter, if it's not day, it should be night, so you could just use a simple else.

Comment: As an aside, I would do this slightly differently.  Since sunrise and sunset are not going to change for a given day, you don't need to check them endlessly.  Calculate the difference between now and the next change and then sleep or set a trigger to change the camera state that much time in the future.